# Which approach is better in using vue.js and laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, web, frontend

Which approach is better when we use react/Vue with laravel:

- react/Vue as separate project
- react/Vue in the same project with laravel

Why? And in what different condition we use these two different approaches?

Answer (score 0):

i think  if you develop SPA you should separate front end and backend, because it run independently. if you use Vue as a part of your website( progressive) you can simply import Vue by script tag in where you want